# Please solve this Dataframe attribute error for prophet

Tags: facebook-prophet, prophet

prophet.fit(ds)
`i was trying to train prophet on ds dataset having two columns ds and y`

For the above code i am getting the below error

ds.columns = [['ds','y']]   `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'`